# Freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 and is very slow

Tags: graphics

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop It's an Intel Pentium 4 processor (Single Core) at 2.80Ghz, 1GB RAM, and for the Graphics its Intel 865G x86/MMX/SSE2 OS is 32 bit.

Boot up is quick and fast, but running anything is slow, it fades in/out slow. I did have 9.4 Jaunty installed but I figured why not upgrade to the latest version. Big mistake. :P

Windows 7 Operated faster than this on this desktop. ahaha.

Is there anyway it could just be graphics? I'm new to this version, but I've used 8,9, and 12, and I found that 12 thus far has been nice to use. But would LOVE to try this Version.

I do have a laptop (Using right now)

It's a Dell Inspiron 1501 (Yes my computers are old, but the laptop I got for free and the desktop I got for $40. :P) 3GB DDR2 RAM, AMD Turion 64 X2 2.00GHz, ATI Radeon Xpress, which is running Windows 7 Ultimate x86.

Would 14.04 benefit on the laptop? :P

Thanks. :)

Comment: You could try the [classic desktop](http://askubuntu.com/q/58172/107450) it's much lighter than Unity and should give you a considerably faster system.

Comment: I might just down grade to 12.04. I have not tried it on this computer. But I know that 9.04 and 8.04 works. :P haha. Oh how i miss those days. lol.

Comment: Ok, so I tried the classic desktop, but it was still to slow. It couldn't be the installation if Wubi was experiencing the same issue. I downloaded 12.04 and it runs fast and smooth like it should. I've never tried 13. Might check it out later and install it along side 12.04. But at least until I can get a better computer, this will have to do. :)

Thanks for all your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 should fly on your laptop. Definitely go ahead and install it.

According to [ubuntu system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements), your pentium 4 should not have serious problems running ubuntu. Are you using the 32bit version? Since you have less than 2 GB of RAM, you should install the 32 bit version of ubuntu. 64 bit version might lag a bit.

A quick way to see if your display drivers are installed is to open up 'details' from the dashboard and look at 'display'. If your chipset is listed there, then the display drivers are proper and graphics is not the reason your system lags.

Comment: It is indeed 32 bit. Biggest reason why I don't want to install Ubuntu on my laptop is that I use Sony Vegas to render YouTube Videos, and other windows based programs for other things. 

Quick Note: When I had windows 7 installed, I used Wubi to install along side Windows, and it was just as slow.

Everything shows up properly in Display.

I'll probably have to go to 12.04.